# nginx unknown property name after \P or \p in "\php$" at "hp$" in nginx.conf

Tags: magento, nginx

Hi When i run bellow command

service nginx configtest i am getting error like bellow screenshot

[image]

Can anyone please help me to resolve it?

HERE IS 53 line number code of my configuration file

```
location ~ \php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

    expires        off;
    fastcgi_pass   luxicocoukbackend;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

backslash should escape a dot

```
location ~ \.php$
```

Comment: Yes now it's done but getting another error now.

[root@luxico ~]# service nginx restart
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:30
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Hi, to solve this problem you should show full file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

Comment: Sometimes there, sometimes in the fastcgi_split_path_info regex
wrong -> ^(.+\php)(/.+)$;
good -> ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;